# Display a specific field using drupal arguments aka"if statement"

Tags: drupal, if-statement, drupal-6, view, arguments

Hello I've tried to make this happen with arguments but have not had much success. I'm sure its something I'm doing wrong. here is my scenario

I have a basic content type of 'News' the content type contains the standard title field and a CCK field called Alternate title. The goal is to create a block view that can print the alternate title if there is one, if the user did not enter an alternate title then the standard title should be printed just like an if statement would function but only with those 2 fields. I'm fairly new to Drupal so wanted to know if this was possible. If I can get pointed in the right direction that would be great. I appreciate any help this community can provide.

Regards

Using Drupal 6 and latest version of views

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved using [Views CustomFeild](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) or [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php)
Just add both the fields in the view, exclude them from display, add third field : the custom-field and you can use php condition in it.

Answer (score 0):

Add both fields in Views UI. 
The order of the fields should be as below.

1. core Title
2. CCK Title

You can have extra stuff above and below these fields for sure. Just keep the order. 
Now, under title field's settings, make it exclude from display (there is a checkbox for that.)

and then, under cck title field's settings, change empty text to the token of the above title field (`[title]` in most cases).

Answer (score 0):

By far the best method according to me would be using [Views customfield](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield).

Add both your fields to the views fields list and exclude both from display.

Add a custom field:Markup and select php code in the input format.

Now write your if else condition here and you are done.